# Calculating a full matrix of shortest path-lengths between all nodes

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

We are trying to find a way to create a **full distance matrix** in a neo4j database, where that distance is defined as the length of the shortest path between any two nodes. Of course, there is the `shortestPath` method but using a loop going through all pairs of nodes and calculating their shortestPaths get very slow. We are explicitely *not* talking about `allShortestPaths`, because that returns all shortest paths between 2 specific nodes.

Is there a specific method or approach that is fast for a large number of nodes (>30k)?

Thank you!
j.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no easier method; the full distance matrix will take a long time to build.**

As you've described it, the full distance matrix must contain the shortest path between any two nodes, which means you will have to get that information at some point. Iterating over each pair of nodes and running a shortest-path algorithm is the only way to do this, and the complexity will be `O(n)` multiplied by the complexity of the algorithm.

**But you can cut down on the runtime with a dynamic programming solution.**

You could certainly leverage some dynamic programming methods to cut down on the calculation time. For instance, if you are trying to find the shortest path between (A) and (C), and have already calculated the shortest from (B) to (C), then if you happen to encounter (B) while pathfinding from (A), you do not need to recalculate the rest of the cost of that path; it is known.

However, creating a dynamic programming solution of any reasonable complexity will almost certainly be best done in a separate module for Neo4J that is thrown in into a plugin. If what you are doing is a one-time operation or an operation that won't be run frequently, it might be easier to just do the naive solution of calling `shortestPath` between each pair, but if you plan to be running it fairly frequently on dynamic data, it might be worth authoring a custom plugin. It totally depends on your needs.

No matter what, though, it will take some time to calculate. The dynamic programming solution will cut down on the time greatly (especially in a densely-connected graph), but it will still not be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

What is the end game? Is this a one-time query that resets some property or creates new edges. Or a recurring frequent effort. If it's one-time, you might create edges between the two nodes at each step creating a transitive closure environment. The edge would point between the two nodes and have, as a property, the distance.

Thus, if the path is a>b>c>d, you would create the edges

```
a>b 1
a>c 2
a>d 3
b>c 1
b>d 2
c>d 1
```

The edges could be named distinctively to distinguish them from the original path edges. This could create circular paths, which may neither negate this strategy or need a constraint. if you are dealing with directed acyclic graphs it would work well.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The end game, as you say, is that we want to optimize a certain algorithm by comparing the distance matrix in a graph with a distance matrix calculated on the original not-yet-converted-into-graph data. Many graphs are created, and we want to check for which ones the distance matrix is closest to the non-graph one.